# What is that ritual performed by the two Mexican assassins?

Tags: plot-explanation, breaking-bad

In S03E01 of *Breaking Bad*, Tuco's two cousins crawl into a temple where they put a sketch of Heisenberg onto a shrine.

There are others doing this ritual too, what is it?

[image]